# Spanning Set And Solution Of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

> Let $\{(2,0,4),(0,1,0),(6,5,12)\}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$
>
> Does $Span\{(2,0,4),(0,1,0),(6,5,12)\}=\mathbb{R}^3$

It can be solved in numerous ways, but the one I am looking for is to prove that the set spans/or does not spans every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$

To do so I put the vectors in a matrix \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 0 & 6\\
0 & 1 & 5\\
4 & 0 & 12\\
\end{pmatrix} and look at the solutions of the homogeneous system? if there no so it does not spans every vector in  $\mathbb{R}^3$?  but what it it has infinite solutions or one solution?

Answer (score 1):

An homogenous system of linear equations alwwyas has a solution: the null solution.

In your case, you have three equations in three unknowns. Then your vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if the system has one and only one solution.

Comment: So I need to solve for $\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}  
 2 & 0 & 6 &a\\  
 0 & 1 & 5 &b \\
 4&0&2&c
\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: @gbox No. Like I said, you can simply solve the homogeneous system. Either it has only one solution or infinitely many. If it has only one solution, then your vectors soan $\mathbb{R}^3$; otherwise, they don't.

Comment: To understand it better 1. Why can I look at the homogeneous system? does nt it answer if it is linear dependent or not?
2. Why can I solve for $Ax=b$?

Comment: 1. The vectors are linearly dependent if and only of the homogeneous system has more than one solution. 2. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Put your vectors $a_1,...,a_n$ into a matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & ... & a_n \end{bmatrix}$.

$Span\{a_1,...,a_n\}=\mathbb{R}^n$, if and only if the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ has only the zero solution. Because this means we can't have $x_1,...x_n$ which are not all zero making $x_1a_1+...+x_na_n=0$. So $a_1,...,a_n$ is linear independent, thus they span the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Regard to you question:

- $Ax=0$ has no solution: It's impossible. A homogeneous system always has a zero solution.
- $Ax=0$ has one solution: The solution must be the zero solution, thus the vectors spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- $Ax=0$ has infinity solutions: There must be a non-zero solution, thus the vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^n$.